# How do you open a link in Safari from the Gmail app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, webview, gmail, mobile-safari

I am sending out an email using the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"subject"];
[controller 
    setMessageBody:@"<a href=\"http://website.com\" target=\"_blank\">Link</a>."
    isHTML:YES
];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the recipient opens this email in the default Mail app and taps the hyperlink, the page opens in Safari. This is the desired behavior. However, if the recipient opens this email in the [Gmail app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gmail-email-from-google/id422689480?mt=8), Gmail presents the page within itself using a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is problematic for me, because somehow Gmail's UIWebView setup has prevented my page's javascript from running (the javascript runs fine when testing with my own UIWebView, however). How would I force Gmail to open my page in Safari instead so my page runs properly?

Comment: That would be a function of the gmail app. You need to contact Google about that. Or perhaps the gmail app has a security setting related to running Javascript.

Comment: @rmaddy I was hoping to find HTML markup that Gmail would respect. I tried `target="_blank"`, but they ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Instead you should concentrate on making your web page capable of determining what features are available in the browser being used to view it and implement graceful degradation so users get the best possible experience however they choose to view the page.