# How to force a link to open in safari instead of webview?

Tags: javascript, webview, safari, mobile-safari, deep-linking

IOS webviews do not support WebRTC - only Safari on IOS does. 
How can I force a page/link to open in real Safari, instead of a webview?

For example, the Gmail app opens all links inside a webview. Instead, I want them to open in Safari.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18282547/how-do-you-open-a-link-in-safari-from-the-gmail-app) SO question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844691/force-ios-facebook-app-to-open-feed-links-in-browser-not-in-webview) one. The simple answer is that what you are looking to do is not possible - that behavior is controlled by the app (gmail or FB). The best you can probably do is "sniff" if the user is inside a webview or non-Safari browser and prompt them to manually switch browser.